# Redirect_to from Devise create to Model create - Using helpers - Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, syntax-error, helper, redirecttoaction

After creating a user with devise (in view/pages not in devise, using Helpers) I redirect them to create a model entry in Papas controller if their role is "Papa" or in Babysitter controller if their role is "Babysitter". 
The thing is I have a strange syntax error since both controllers (Papa & Babysitter) are practically equal. It gives me:

> SyntaxError in PapasController#new
>   /Users/Seba/Desktop/PP/laguarderia/app/controllers/papas_controller.rb:75:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

But not with the BabysitterController#new

This is the controller:

```
class PapasController < InheritedResources::Base
 before_action :set_papa, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]
  # GET /postulantes
  # GET /postulantes.json
  def index
    @papas = Papa.all
  end

  # GET /postulantes/1
  # GET /postulantes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /postulantes/new
  def new
    @papa = Papa.new
  end

  # GET /postulantes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /postulantes
  # POST /postulantes.json
  def create
    @papa = Papa.new(papa_params)
    @papa.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @papa.save
        format.html { redirect_to @papa, notice: '¡Tu postulación fue recibida con exito! Nos contactaremos contigo dentro de los próximos días.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @papas }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @papas.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /postulantes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /postulantes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @papa.update(papa_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @papa, notice: 'Postulante was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @papa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /postulantes/1
  # DELETE /postulantes/1.json
  def destroy
    @papa.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to papas_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_papa
      @papa = Papa.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def papa_params
      params.require(:papa).permit(:nombre, :apellido1, :apellido2, :rut, :cumple, :estadocivil, :email, :cel, :fijo, :ciudad, :comuna, :calle, :numero, :depto, :profesion, :empresa, :cargo, :colegiohijos, :cantidadhijos, :edadhijos, :necesidad, :comentario, :user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

This is my helper:

```
module PagesHelper
  def resource_name
  :user
  end

  def resource
  @resource = current_user || User.new
        if @contact.save
            if current_user.role == "Papa" 
              flash[:success] = "Thanks! I'll be in touch soon!"
              redirect_to :action => 'papas/new'            
            elsif current_user.role == "Babysitter"
              flash[:success] = "Thanks! I'll be in touch soon!"
                redirect_to :action => 'babysitters/new'
            else
              flash[:success] = "hola"  
              redirect_to :action => 'home'
            end 
        else
            redirect_to :action => 'home'
        end
    end

  def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

end
```

---

I realized what was the problem. It wasn´t the controller, it was a missing end in the form rendered that was controlled by this controller... silly things that you miss :/

Answer (score 1):

**Error**

I don't know how experienced you are with Rails, but as a rule, the error you received essentially means you have not closed a particular code block.

This can either be a problem with closing a bracket, including some sort of variable declaration, or generally just not having the required `end` definitions

--

**Controller**

Firstly, you're using `inherited_resources` but I don't understand why you're setting methods like `new`,`show`, `edit`, `set_papa` etc. `Inherited Reources` means you don't have to set those -

```
Class PapasController < InheritedResources::Base
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new]

  # POST /postulantes
  # POST /postulantes.json
  def create
    @papa = Papa.new(papa_params)
    @papa.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @papa.save
        format.html { redirect_to @papa, notice: '¡Tu postulación fue recibida con exito! Nos contactaremos contigo dentro de los próximos días.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @papas }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @papas.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /postulantes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /postulantes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @papa.update(papa_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @papa, notice: 'Postulante was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @papa.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /postulantes/1
  # DELETE /postulantes/1.json
  def destroy
    @papa.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to papas_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def papa_params
      params.require(:papa).permit(:nombre, :apellido1, :apellido2, :rut, :cumple, :estadocivil, :email, :cel, :fijo, :ciudad, :comuna, :calle, :numero, :depto, :profesion, :empresa, :cargo, :colegiohijos, :cantidadhijos, :edadhijos, :necesidad, :comentario, :user_id)
  end
end
```

--

**Fix**

I think the problem is to do with the 3 `end`s you have the at the end of the class:

```
    end
  end
end
```

I think you're trying to close the `private` block, when it doesn't require an end. Remove one of the `end`s here - (to give you `2`) - and it should work for you

Comment: yep, that's the fix. This is why I generally unindent the `private` keyword, or keep it at the same level as the methods below it - uneven unindenting looks wonky

Comment: When I remove 'end' for private, the console gives me two errors regarding end of input expecting keyword end. The method definitions are created automatically with scaffold. I´m using ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]. This doesn´t fix the problem, I already tried that... Do you have any ideas? I really think there´s something in the interaction with helper. Just a hunch, i´m not very experimented in ruby on rails.